# ‘06 Ford Ranger

Tags: ford, starting, ranger, intermittent-problems

My ranger started less than a week ago not starting. When I turn the key to the on position. It’s basically dead. The airbag light is dimly lit. It’s also reset the clock. The security light flickers and flashes. Makes all sorts of noises and clicks.  Yesteday I replaced broken bushings for the shifter that made it feel loose. And the starting control module looks ok. Then the next second starts like there’s no issue. And it will be ok for the next several starts. Then act up again.

Battery is brand new. And battery clamps are brand new.

If need be I have a video of what the dash lights are doing when it doesn’t want to start.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: ..I wonder if it could be a faulty ignition switch not properly sensing the key position. A couple things I'd try: Do you get the same effect using your spare key? Can you carefully push the key to the on position boundaries to see if the contact points catch somewhere and the electrics come to life? ....hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: When it does not start- does your check engine light go out when switch is held in the cranking position?

Answer (score 0):

People on the Ford Taurus website often say to clean the ground straps that connect from the engine to the chassis.